# When can the value of a given number be obtained as the absolute value of a sum of complex roots of unity?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, trigonometry, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

In researching a kind of geometric problem I have found the following integer parameter dependent constant, geometrically describing the circumradius of some regular $m$-gon:

$$ \rho(m,\mu) = \frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m}+\mu\frac{\pi}{m}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{m}\right)\sin\left(\mu\frac{\pi}{m}\right)} $$

Here, $m>4$ and $\left\lceil m/2 \right\rceil-1 > \mu > 0$. The latter condition guarantees that $\rho(m,\mu)$ is positive.

Now, I have observed that $\rho(m,\mu)$ sometimes can be obtained as the absolute value of a sum of complex roots of unity $\omega_{m}^{k} = \exp(i 2 \pi k / m)$ (= basic vectors of unit length in the $m$ orientations of the $m$-gon). Namely,

$$ \rho(m,\mu) = \left|\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}c_{k}\omega_{m}^{k}\right| $$

with non-negative integer coefficients $c_{k}$. For instance,

$$\rho(8,1) = \left|\omega_{8}^{1}+\omega_{8}^{0}+\omega_{8}^{7}\right|$$

$$\rho(10,1) = \left|\omega_{10}^{0}+2\omega_{10}^{1}+2\omega_{10}^{9}\right|$$

$$\rho(10,2) = \left|\omega_{10}^{1}+\omega_{10}^{9}\right|$$

$$\rho(10,3) = \left|\omega_{10}^{2}+\omega_{10}^{8}\right|$$

$$\rho(12,1) = \left|2\omega_{12}^{1}+3\omega_{12}^{0}+2\omega_{12}^{11}\right|$$

$$\rho(12,2) = \left|\omega_{12}^{1}+\omega_{12}^{0}+\omega_{12}^{11}\right|$$

Thus, the problem is, geometrically, when can the circumradius vector of a regular $m$-gon of a given length be constructed from the m-th roots of unity interpreted as $m$ basic vectors in the complex plane?

However, trying to find examples for all admissible parameters according to the aforementioned conditions by some exhaustive computer search was futile. In particular, I did not find any solutions for odd $m$, but also not always a full set of solutions for even $m$ and all possible values of $\mu$. I guess, there are no solutions for all possible parameter choices of $m$ and $\mu$.

My question is, can one show/proof that only certain combinations of parameters have such a construction by complex roots of unity? And maybe find all the possible constructions? And maybe explain, why the other cases are impossible?

I have no idea, how to proceed. One observation I made is that sums of complex roots of unity appear as roots of abelian polynomials, but I don't know if that helps?

Comment: What does $\mu$ represent?

Comment: $\mu$ is a non-negative integer parameter bounded from above by $m$. In my geometric problem it describes some distinct cases, for fixed $m$, and thus appears in the circumradius mentioned above, but otherwise does not have a simple geometrical interpretation (as far as I know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One observation is that the absolute value of a sum of roots of unity is an algebraic integer.  If $m$ and $\mu$ are integers, $\rho(m,\mu)$ is an algebraic number, but if is not an algebraic integer (i.e. if it is a root of a monic irreducible polynomial whose coefficients are rational but not all integers), then it is not the absolute value of a sum of roots of unity. For example, $\rho(7,1)$ is a root of
$z^3 - z^2 - z -1/7$, and therefore is not an algebraic integer.

Comment: That sounds like a quite general observation and possibly is already the solution. The only question now is, how difficult is it to check whether some value of $\rho(m,\mu)$ is the root of such a polynomial, that means to find this polynomial if it exists (easy?), or show that it does not exist (hard? but then one might find an example by exhaustive search rather quickly). Is there a straightforward method to find such a polynomial from one given root alone? Is this related to some other property of the $m$-gon?

Comment: Ah, I think it is easy to find the (minimal) polynomial and perform the check for $\rho(m,\mu)$ being an algebraic integer, as Mathematica has built-in commands for both. For all the cases I want to consider I can perform the checks manually. Maybe you can still help me once more and tell me if there is a source to cite for the facts you stated or if that is some basic mathematical knowledge? And also, might I ask you, if you would be OK with being mentioned in the acknowledgements in case I write this down in an article, as an explanation why only certain solutions are possible?

Comment: The basic facts about algebraic integers can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer).  I'm OK with being mentioned in acknowledgements.